# How to show/hide material design lite spinner using javascript

Tags: javascript, material-design

I am refreing this document.

https://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#loading-section

i can show spinner using this HTML code.

```
<div class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active"></div>
<!-- MDL Spinner Component with Single Color -->
<div class="mdl-spinner mdl-spinner--single-color mdl-js-spinner is-active">
</div>
```

But i want same thing to be done using java script code. for example on click of a button show spinner and on click of another button hide same spinner.

How to achieve same with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('show').onclick=function(){
   document.getElementById('spin1').style.display = 'block'; 
};

document.getElementById('hide').onclick=function(){
   document.getElementById('spin1').style.display = 'none'; 
};
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>

<!-- MDL Spinner Component -->
<div id="spin1" class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active"></div>
<!-- MDL Spinner Component with Single Color -->
<div id="spin2" class="mdl-spinner mdl-spinner--single-color mdl-js-spinner is-active"></div>

<button id="show">show</button>
<button id="hide">hide</button>
```

Using `display 'none'` and `display: 'block'`
Part of your question is to show it with javascript, when clicking a show button. I'd suggest adding this html to the dom, but making it hidden by default. This way you don't have to insert html by javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('show').onclick=function(){
   document.getElementById('spin1').style.display = 'block'; 
};

document.getElementById('hide').onclick=function(){
   document.getElementById('spin1').style.display = 'none'; 
};
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>

<!-- MDL Spinner Component -->
<div id="spin1" class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active"></div>
<!-- MDL Spinner Component with Single Color -->
<div id="spin2" class="mdl-spinner mdl-spinner--single-color mdl-js-spinner is-active"></div>

<button id="show">show</button>
<button id="hide">hide</button>
```

Changing the display attribute seems to break something with the spinner in IE11. After the 'hide' the 'show' displays the element again, but the spinner isn't visible at all.